# Why do I get error 462 while imported excel using Access VBA?

Tags: excel, import

I have an access database with I import multiple excel spreadsheets one at a time. Before importing I open the spreadsheet and sort it.  Works fine the first time, but the second time and any additional times, I get error 462.  I notice that the spreadsheet never really closes, so I think that may be the issue, but I don't know what it doesn't close.  Below is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdImport_ClassConfig_Data_Click()
Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant
Dim ConfigFile As String
Dim exlFile As excel.Application
Dim wbk As excel.Workbook
Dim wst As excel.Worksheet

On Error GoTo Import_Posting_Dates_Error

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM ClassConfiguration"
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select your CONFIG file."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xlsx"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\%UserName%\My Documents\*xlsx"
        If .Show = True Then
            For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
                ConfigFile = varFile
            Next
        End If
    End With

Set exlFile = New excel.Application
Set wbk = exlFile.Workbooks.Open(ConfigFile, , False)
exlFile.visible = True
Set wst = wbk.Worksheets(1)
wst.Sort.SortFields.Clear
wst.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A43527"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With wst.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:AA4000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
wbk.Close True
Set wbk = Nothing
exlFile.Quit
Set exlFile = Nothing

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ClassConfiguration", ConfigFile, True

Dim sUIC As String
sUIC = Me.DDTVSTShipLog.Controls("UIC")

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO ClassConfiguration1 ( ID, ric, p_ric, UIC, sei, esd, EIC, work_center, rin, quantity, prid, Location, serial_number, efd, RIC_NOMENC, service_application_cd, hsc, [SELECT], alt_ric, sac ) " & _
    "SELECT ClassConfiguration.ID, ClassConfiguration.ric, ClassConfiguration.p_ric, Right([ClassConfiguration].[UIC],5) AS UICS, ClassConfiguration.sei, ClassConfiguration.esd, ClassConfiguration.EIC, ClassConfiguration.wcr_equip AS work_center, ClassConfiguration.rin, ClassConfiguration.quantity, ClassConfiguration.prid, ClassConfiguration.Location, ClassConfiguration.serial_number, ClassConfiguration.efd, ClassConfiguration.ric_nomenclature AS RIC_NOMENC, ClassConfiguration.sac AS service_application_cd, ClassConfiguration.hsc, ClassConfiguration.[SELECT], ClassConfiguration.alt_ric, ClassConfiguration.sac " & _
    "FROM Configuration1 RIGHT JOIN ClassConfiguration ON Configuration1.ric = ClassConfiguration.ric " & _
    "WHERE ((Not (Right([ClassConfiguration].[UIC],5))='" & sUIC & "') AND ((Configuration1.ric) Is Null));"

Me.Refresh
Forms("Build Visit Database").Refresh
   
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox "Class Config Import complete.  Compact are Repair Database before continuing with next import.", vbOKOnly, "Import Complete"
Exit Sub

Import_Posting_Dates_Error:
If Err.Number = 2522 Then ' 2522 missing argument (File Name) - i.e no file selected
    MsgBox "No file selected, operation cancelled " & "( " & Err.Number & " ).", vbInformation, "APP NAME"
Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")", vbInformation, "APP NAME"
End If
Me.Refresh
    
End Sub
```

As you can see I do close it and set it to nothing, but it still exists for some reason.

Thanks,
Pat

Comment: You have unqualified range calls. Use `wst.Range` not just `Range` in both instances.

Comment: Rory, That worked!  I have had this issue for so long, it was driving me crazy!  Thank you so much, for such an easy fix it caused me nightmares!  Thanks Again.